# How do I format an unix timestamp to RFC3339 - golang?

Tags: go

I need to convert a unix  timestamp ( e.g `1392899576` ) into RFC3339 ( e.g. 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00 ) . I've tried the code below

```
    timeValue := "1392899576"
    layout := time.RFC3339
    t, _ := time.Parse(layout, timeValue)

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", t)
```

which returns

```
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The term "Parse" usually means a procedure that converts a string representation of something into the internal language representation for the same thing.

What you want is the opposite of Parse, "Format":

```
time.Unix(1392899576, 0).Format(time.RFC3339)
```